# Entity Framework Foreign Key Table isn't saving changes made to its BindingSource

Tags: c#, data-binding, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `Vehicles` (
    `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ... Other columns
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

And:

```
CREATE TABLE `VehicleOptions` (
    `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `VehicleID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    ... Other columns
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
    KEY `FK_Vehicles_to_VehicleOptions` (`VehicleID`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_Vehicles_to_VehicleOptions` FOREIGN KEY (`VehicleID`) REFERENCES `vehicles` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Here is a picture of the Data Objects:

[image: Data Objects]

I drag and dropped Vehicle and VehicleOptions onto my form. I then load the databse using a LINQ query:

```
var dataSource = from v in Database.DataContext.Vehicles.Include("VehicleOptions")
                 orderby v.Stock descending
                 select v;

// The vehicles BindingSource
bsVehicles.DataSource = dataSource;

// The vehicleoptions BindingSource
bsVehicleOptions.DataSource = bsVehicles;
bsVehicleOptions.DataMember = "VehicleOptions";
```

Whenever I add/edit data on my form I call:

```
bsVehicles.SuspendBinding();
bsVehicleOptions.SuspendBinding();
Database.DataContext.SaveChanges();
bsVehicleOptions.ResumeBinding();
bsVehicles.ResumeBinding();
```

The changes made to `bsVehicles` are saved in my MySQL database but the changes made to `bsVehicleOptions` are not.  Even on the form, the Controls bound to `bsVehicleOptions` empty their data on `Database.DataContext.SaveChanges();`  Am I missing something here?

Note: I am using the Entity Framework V4 (I've hear the Associations in older versions were funky?).

Comment: Can you try detach and then attach the VehicleOptions into the Vehicles object graph and then call context.SaveChanges()?

Comment: Detach it from the data context? What if the VehicleOptions don't exist yet (Im adding a new Vehicle for example)?

Comment: the link to the image is borken.

Comment: why are you doing the suspend/ resume bindings surrounding the save?